# error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

Tags: apt, 20.04, android, repository, ssl

Using Ubuntu20.04 version and I was able to clone the android source code but suddenly something went wrong in my system and now I am unable to clone the Android source code.

```
 $repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
 Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
 fatal: error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to 
 get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
fatal: double check your --repo-rev setting.
 fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

Tried to install the repo,

```
$sudo apt-get install repo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package repo
```

It seems the repo was uninstalled and now I am unable to install it.

I spent much time on this to fix this issue, but google solutions are not helped.
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you.